# Pandas - Merge rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to cleanup some data

The dataframe currently look something like this:

```
    id  data data2
0   12  NaN  50.0
1   12  a    50.0
2   12  a    NaN
3   52  b    NaN
4   52  NaN  20.0
5   52  NaN  20.0
```

I'd like to collapse the rows to remove duplicate entries and keep only what's valid grouping on ID in this specific case, disregarding NaNs and and up with:

```
    id  data data2
0   12  a    50
1   52  b    20
```

Comment: Did you call pd.concat on two dataFrames before this?

Comment: no, this data is provided to me as is

Comment: So what do you mean by "disregarding NaNs"? What are the duplicates here? Your question is a bit broad.

Comment: You're right - I forgot to specify it should group using the ID column.

I edited the question for clarification - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: So, `df.groupby('id').first()`?

Comment: It is indeed! I figured there must have been a way to do this that'd be simple, I did not expect /that/ simple though.

Comment: Once you can explain the question, the solution presents itself. Good luck!

Comment: I ended up deleting my answer :) @coldspeed, way to go.

Comment: @HarvIpan Not 100% sure, but it may be duplicate. Feel free to edit your answer with my comment, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
    id  data    data2
0   12  a      50.0
1   52  b      20.0
```

Comment: @coldspeed, thank you.